# Losing values after refreshing button asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, autopostback

I have the following project :

It's a page that on `Page_Load` it fills a TextBox named **Email** and a TextBox named **UserName** with a value obtained from asking a database.

Then there is this button, if the email is not null(user is not registered) it will let you register, otherwise it will let you change the email linked to your username.

The thing is, when trying to modify the email, doing an update query, the page preloads, taking the new value placed on Textbox **Email** the same that is retrieved from the database, making so it will never change.

I've tried to see if it executes the query and it does.

I've tried everything, keeping the variable on a hidden label, creating two different buttons with no luck as when it reloads the code those values are empty again.

I was thinking if I could keep the variable somehow that isn't cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I think You know What is happening.. On every Post back the `Page_Load` event resetting your Textbox Value

Use `IsPostBack` to bind the value only on 1st load of page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      //bind dropdown and fill textbox here
        TxtName.Text = "Your values";
        GetDropdowns();
    }
}
```

I hope this will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Kanis XXX, you can use IsPostBack to fill the values only at the start page, and not on other postbacks. In my experience, there are some other advices for your problems:

- Using Viewstate, Session state,... to keep your working variable. You can have more detail here: https://kimphuc.wordpress.com/2009/10/18/the-difference-between-viewstate-sessionstate-cookies-and-cache-in-asp-net/
- Try to use UpdatePanel, this could be useful in some cases, let you refresh or update data just a part of your page, not the whole page. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb398864%28v=vs.100%29.aspx